# gcc make on crouton?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have crouton linux running on my samsung chromebook.  cc works fine, but there is no 'make' command.  I tried "apt-get install gcc" but it said I already had the latest gcc.

I am porting a complex project with a big Makefile, and really do need make.  Also would appreciate "bitmap" or some other icon editor, and even a C-savvy editor like emacs or gedit.
How do I get these?  I thought they all came with GCC.  Thanks, mike k.

Answer (score 2):

make and your compiler (in this case gcc) are entirely unrelated pieces of software. make is likely to be in the make package. make executes commands (of whatever sort it is told to run which may or may not have anything to do with compiling code).

The situation with emacs, gedit, etc. is similar.